# SQL запрос для поиска словосочетаний в тексте?

Tags: mysql, sql

Нужен простой но нормальный поиск по БД для сайта. К примеру, что бы так же он мог искать как одиночные слова, так и словосочетания.

К примеру запрос для поиска такой: "xxx yyy" и, что бы возвращалась информация в тексте которой есть "xxx yyy", а так же в тексте которой есть хотя бы "xxx" или "yyy" или "yyy xxx" или "xxx%yyy" или "yyy%xxx" (% - в лучших традициях SQL, любая последовательность любых символов).

Ну в общем обычный адекватный поиск без всяких наворотов вроде отгадывания неправильного написания слов или поиска похожих слов.

Такое возможно вообще сделать при помощи одного SQL запроса?

Comment: За ссылку на FullText Index огромное спасибо. Хотя он тоже не ICE, буду наверное писать все 6 вариантов (в порядке убывания релевантности) запросов с использованием LIKE.

Comment: @platinumixq а если в тексте есть слово axxxyyyb?

Comment: ну тогда запросы LIKE "%xxx%" и LIKE "%ууу%" его выберут, что будет весьма не плохо ведь скорее всего это какое либо словообразование, которое имеет отношение к запросу. Ничего страшного думаю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL поддерживает полнотекстовый поиск. [Здесь](http://www.php.su/mysql/manual/?page=Fulltext_Search) можно почитать и посмотреть примеры.

Answer (score 1):

Можно разбить слова в один массив отдельных слов и искать при помощи like слова